# Extending PXMappedCacheExtension

Tags: acumatica

Does anyone have an example of how to add a field to a Mapped cache extension? I am trying to extend the SalesPrice functionality in 2019R1. It looks a lot like a DAC... but something tells me I cant simply just make an extension for it..

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please see below the diagram showing how it works.
[image]

In short, you create a generic graph and a class inherited from PXMapppedCacheExtension which will have all the fields that you need for your reusable logic.
Then you declare the mapping to the class and the implementation of the generic graph.

Please find the complete description by the following [link](https://help-2018r1.acumatica.com/Wiki/ShowWiki.aspx?pageid=bbc04253-7686-41dd-898b-aca47c1c6789).